# React-native stand alone app crashing after kill port 8081

Tags: ios, react-native

I build a release version of react-native ios app but the app is crashing when I kill port `8081`.

Comment: May i know the build process you followed

Answer (score 0):

You have to bundle the assets before building the application,

Step 1: Run this command inside your react native project

```
react-native bundle --entry-file index.js --platform ios --dev false --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ios
```

Step 2: Edit your build scheme from debug to release.

Step 3: Replace the code inside the appdelegate.m file

```
jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
```

to this

```
jsCodeLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
```

Now you can build the release version of your ios app.

Hope this helps ;-)